# Sphinx "WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class" error

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to use Sphinx to generate docs for some python class
I've one python script with one class (with some docs)

My python script is here: D:\sphynx\scripts\src\test.py

Not sure if this is correct , but this is my test.rst

```
.. automodule:: src
Base Class
----------
.. autoclass:: Test
   :members:
```

modules.rst

```
scripts
=======

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   test
```

```
class Test(object):
    """ test docs 
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Initialize a Test object.
        """
        self._params = kwargs
    def my_method(self, param):
        """ method docs here
        Args:
            param: Input param.
        Returns:
            Test: Returns self.
        """
        return self
```

index.rst

```
.. Test documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Mon Sep  9 11:45:25 2019.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to Pets's documentation!
================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   modules

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

conf.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('D:/sphynx/scripts'))

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
```

Once I run 'make html' command, I get this error:

```
D:\sphynx>make html
...
reading sources... [100%] test
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'Test' from module 'src'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\util\inspect.py", line 230, in safe_getattr
    return getattr(obj, name, *defargs)
AttributeError: module 'src' has no attribute 'Test'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc\importer.py", line 71, in import_object
    obj = attrgetter(obj, attrname)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc\__init__.py", line 226, in get_attr
    return autodoc_attrgetter(self.env.app, obj, name, *defargs)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc\__init__.py", line 1501, in autodoc_attrgetter
    return safe_getattr(obj, name, *defargs)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\util\inspect.py", line 246, in safe_getattr
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: Test

looking for now-outdated files... none found
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no module named `src`. The `Test` class is defined in the `test` module (test.py). `.. automodule:: test` should work, with `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('D:/sphynx/scripts/src'))` in conf.py.

Answer (score 2):

There is no module named `src`. It is just a folder. The `Test` class is defined in the `test` module (test.py) which is in that folder.

`.. automodule:: test` should work for you, with `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('D:/sphynx/scripts/src'))` in conf.py.